# Load first 10 items from array and then next 10 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, es6-promise

I am working on react project , where I have an array list of items . I want to load first 10 items on initial rendering and need to show a button name as ( more record )at bottom when user click on this button I want to show next 10 items from array but I also want to show previous array items . Means if user click on ( more record ) I want to show 20 records and when user click on button again I want to show 10 next items which will be equal to 30 ( previous 20 and new 10 ) . I am new to react could someone please help me how to resolve this issue.
thanks.

**Data**

```
 [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "illo expedita consequatur quia in",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "quo adipisci enim quam ut ab",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "molestiae perspiciatis ipsa",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "illo est ratione doloremque quia maiores aut",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 11,
    "title": "vero rerum temporibus dolor",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 12,
    "title": "ipsa repellendus fugit nisi",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 13,
    "title": "et doloremque nulla",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 14,
    "title": "repellendus sunt dolores architecto voluptatum",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 15,
    "title": "ab voluptatum amet voluptas",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 16,
    "title": "accusamus eos facilis sint et aut voluptatem",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 17,
    "title": "quo laboriosam deleniti aut qui",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 18,
    "title": "dolorum est consequatur ea mollitia in culpa",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 19,
    "title": "molestiae ipsa aut voluptatibus pariatur dolor nihil",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 20,
    "title": "ullam nobis libero sapiente ad optio sint",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 21,
    "title": "suscipit repellat esse quibusdam voluptatem incidunt",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 22,
    "title": "distinctio vitae autem nihil ut molestias quo",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 23,
    "title": "et itaque necessitatibus maxime molestiae qui quas velit",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 24,
    "title": "adipisci non ad dicta qui amet quaerat doloribus ea",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 25,
    "title": "voluptas quo tenetur perspiciatis explicabo natus",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 26,
    "title": "aliquam aut quasi",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 27,
    "title": "veritatis pariatur delectus",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 28,
    "title": "nesciunt totam sit blanditiis sit",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 29,
    "title": "laborum aut in quam",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 30,
    "title": "nemo perspiciatis repellat ut dolor libero commodi blanditiis omnis",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 31,
    "title": "repudiandae totam in est sint facere fuga",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 32,
    "title": "earum doloribus ea doloremque quis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 33,
    "title": "sint sit aut vero",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 34,
    "title": "porro aut necessitatibus eaque distinctio",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 35,
    "title": "repellendus veritatis molestias dicta incidunt",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 36,
    "title": "excepturi deleniti adipisci voluptatem et neque optio illum ad",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 37,
    "title": "sunt cum tempora",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 38,
    "title": "totam quia non",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 39,
    "title": "doloremque quibusdam asperiores libero corrupti illum qui omnis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 40,
    "title": "totam atque quo nesciunt",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 41,
    "title": "aliquid amet impedit consequatur aspernatur placeat eaque fugiat suscipit",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 42,
    "title": "rerum perferendis error quia ut eveniet",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 43,
    "title": "tempore ut sint quis recusandae",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 44,
    "title": "cum debitis quis accusamus doloremque ipsa natus sapiente omnis",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 45,
    "title": "velit soluta adipisci molestias reiciendis harum",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 46,
    "title": "vel voluptatem repellat nihil placeat corporis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 47,
    "title": "nam qui rerum fugiat accusamus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 48,
    "title": "sit reprehenderit omnis quia",
    "completed": false
  },
 
]
```

Comment: What have you tried that didnt work? This site is not meant to come here with a question without any work being put in by you to solve the problem before hand. Show us what you tried, and what happened when you tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it so

```
const List = () => {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(10);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.slice(0, listItems).map(rec => {
        return <div>{rec.id}</div>
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setListItems(listItems + 10)} >Show more...</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Data is your array. I created state with number of items, default 10. When you press the button, you increase this state at 10

You can check how it looks [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-rgb-nxsw6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This way will work only if you use functional react

Comment: Thank You .!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const [more, setMore] = useState(10)

yourArray.map((data, i)=>{
        if(i>more) return null
        return (
           <div>{data.value}</div>
         )
})
    
<button onClick={()=> setMore(c=> c+10)}>More Data</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your data you could set it to your state value with a useEffect() on component mount, then update using a callback function that sets the state to the second part of your array. To split the data into two chunks you can just use array.slice.

```
const Items = () => {
  const data = [];
  const firstTen = data.slice(0, 10);
  const secondTen = data.slice(10, 20);

  const [itemsToShow, setItemsToShow] = useState(firstTen);
  const handleShowNextPage = () => setItemsToShow(secondTen);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(itemsToShow)}</div>
      <button onClick={handleShowNextPage}>Show Next Page</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```